# Transfer contents of directory over net's TCP connection

Tags: go

I am currently learning Go and I am trying to send the contents of a directory to another machine over a plain tcp connection using Go's net package. 
It works fine with individual files and small folders, but I run into issues if the folder contains many subfolders and larger files. I am using the `filepath.Walk` function to traverse over all files in the given directory. For each file or directory I send, I also send a header that provides the receiver with file name, file size, isDir properties so I know for how long I need to read for when reading the content. **The issue I am having is that after a while when reading the header, I am reading actual file content of the previous file even though I already read that file from the connection**

Here is the writer side. I simply traverse over the directory.

```
func transferDir(session *Session, dir string) error {
  return filepath.Walk(dir, func(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    header := Header{Name: info.Name(), Size: info.Size(), Path: path}

    if info.IsDir() {
        header.SetDirBit()
        session.WriteHeader(header)
        return nil // nothing more to write
    }

    // content is a file. write the file now byte by byte
    file, err := os.Open(path)
    inf, err := file.Stat()

    header.Size = inf.Size() // get the true size of the file

    session.WriteHeader(header)

    defer file.Close()

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    buf := make([]byte, BUF_SIZE)

    for {
        n, err := file.Read(buf)

        if err != nil {
            if err == io.EOF {
                session.Write(buf[:n])
                session.Flush()
                break
            } else {
                log.Println(err)
                return err
            }
        }

        session.Write(buf[:n])
        session.Flush()
    }

    return nil

})
```

And here is the reader part

```
func (c *Clone) readFile(h Header) error {
    file, err := os.Create(h.Path)
    defer file.Close()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    var receivedByts int64
    fmt.Printf("Reading File: %s Size: %d\n", h.Name, h.Size)
    for {
        if (h.Size - receivedByts) < BUF_SIZE {
            n, err := io.CopyN(file, c.sesh, (h.Size - receivedByts))
            fmt.Println("Written: %d err: %s\n", n, err)
            break
        }

        n, err := io.CopyN(file, c.sesh, BUF_SIZE)
        fmt.Println("Written: %d err: %s\n", n, err)
        receivedByts += BUF_SIZE
        fmt.Println("Bytes Read: ", receivedByts)
    }

    return nil
}
```

Now the weird part is that when I am looking at the print statements I see something like:
Reading File: test.txt Size: 14024

Written 1024 nil

Bytes Read 1024

... This continues all the way to the break statement

And the total of the Bytes read equals the actual file size. Yet, the subsequent read for the header will return content from the test.txt file. Almost like there is still stuff in the buffer, but I think I read it already....

Comment: The reader attempts to copy BUF_SIZE bytes on every iteration of the copy loop. If the file is not a multiple of BUF_SIZE bytes or the file is not padded to the size, then the reader will get out of sync with the writer.  I don't know for sure because there's a lot of code that you are not showing. Consider replacing the reader loop with  `_, err := io.CopyN(file, c.sesh, h.Size)`.  The loop in the writer can also be replaced with io.CopyN.  Also, share the complete code.

Comment: @ThunderCat I feel like an idiot. Been looking at this for almost 24 hours now not realizing that my `session.Write(buf[:n])` should be `session.Write(buf)`. Your comment about the padded size and reader out of sync made me realize it. So thank you.

Comment: Consider simplifying the code by replacing each of the copy loops with a single call to io.CopyN.  The [archive/tar](https://godoc.org/archive/tar) may be of interest to you. You are duplicating functionality in that package.

Comment: Thanks! I refactored to use archive/tar. Much less code